# Compare two xml based on the tag as unique tag

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlunit-2

I am developing application in which I have to compare 2 xml based on the IPADDRESS tag which is unique.
    Ex: input1.xml

```
          <DeviceList>
                <Device>
                  <IPAddress>20.20.1.20</IPAddress>
                  <HostName>Device1</HostName>
                </Device>
                <Device>
                  <IPAddress>20.20.1.21</IPAddress>
                  <HostName>Device2</HostName>
                </Device>
                <Device>
                  <IPAddress>20.20.1.22</IPAddress>
                  <HostName>Device3</HostName>
                </Device>
           </DeviceList>

            inpu2.xml
          <DeviceList>
                <Device>
                  <IPAddress>20.20.1.23</IPAddress>
                  <HostName>Device1</HostName>
                </Device>
                <Device>
                  <IPAddress>20.20.1.21</IPAddress>
                  <HostName>Device3</HostName>
                </Device>
                <Device>
                  <IPAddress>20.20.1.22</IPAddress>
                  <HostName>Device3</HostName>
                </Device>
         </DeviceList>

Result should be two xmls 
output1 : ipadrees are present in input2.xml and not present in input.xml1


  <DeviceList>
      <Device>
          <IPAddress>10.20.1.23</IPAddress>
          <HostName>Device1</HostName>
      </Device>
  </DeviceList>

output2 : Remaining device list in input1.xml

 <DeviceList>
          <Device>
      <IPAddress>10.20.1.20</IPAddress>
      <HostName>Device1</HostName>
    </Device>
    <Device>
      <IPAddress>10.20.1.21</IPAddress>
      <HostName>Device2</HostName>
    </Device>
    <Device>
      <IPAddress>10.20.1.22</IPAddress>
      <HostName>Device3</HostName>
    </Device>
  </DeviceList>
```

I tried using XMLUNIT java api but not able to do as we should filter only based on IPAddress tag.Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are collecting the differences between the two documents and want to emit the ones where the difference is `CHILD_LOOKUP` and only use those where the side representing input1 is null.

What you need here is the exact same as the HTML Table example from https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes - you want an `ElementQualifier` that usually matches XML elements by name but in the special case of the `Device` element you want to match those elements that have the same text content inside of their `IPAddress` child element.

This would be something like

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("Device")
        .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./IPAddress", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```